# Diamondback install size

Tags: ros, installation, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How big is the full installation? I currently have <5GB of free space on my root partition (the cturtle on my system is about 3.9GB). Is it safe to mount the /opt folder to another partition?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9244/diamondback-install-size/) by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 475 on 2011-02-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no "full" installation of ROS as ROS supports many different types of robots.  It sounds like you installed the "pr2all" version of ROS C Turtle, which comes with many PR2-specific capabilities.

In Diamondback, we have tried to streamline the stacks that you get when you install.  The packages themselves are also about half their size in C Turtle.

The following are the sizes of some recommended installs:

442MB ros-diamondback-desktop
1.1GB ros-diamondback-desktop-full

NOTE: you have to install drivers separately.

If you need to use arm navigation, which is still experimental, it will add about 500MB to your installation.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on 2011-03-01**:
Looks like a nodev option is fine. roscore is running fine and I have launched a couple of nodes.

**Comment by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on 2011-03-01**:
What about mounting /opt to another partition? Is it safe (not running any ros commands)? I'm also not sure what my options should be on the fstab.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-03-01**:
Yes, those are binary packages.

**Comment by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on 2011-03-01**:
What I mean by "full" installation is really the desktop-full install, and btw I installed the cturtle-base. Is that 1.1GB already built?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-03-01**:
If I interpret apt-get correctly, the download size is about 25%

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-01**:
How large is the download size compared to the unpacked size? Once in a while I run into problems where I cannot even download all of the updates at once because I have so little free space on the robot.